# Maximum bantime with fail2ban

Tags: linux, nginx, fail2ban, firewalld

I am using `fail2ban/firewalld` to restrict bot-like access to a `Nginx` server. Typically, the configuration of the corresponding jail looks like:

```
[nginx-botsearch]
#banaction = iptables-multiport
enabled = true
filter = nginx-botsearch
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = 3600
```

This works as expected (the banaction defaults to `firewallcmd-ipset`), i.e., the `iptables -L` command shows an entry in the `INPUT_direct` chain:

```
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https match-set fail2ban-nginx-botsearch src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

with the corresponding `ipset` of `fail2ban-nginx-botsearch`.

However, I noticed a strange behavior when the `bantime` is increased. Everything works as expected for `bantime <= 4294967`. When I set `bantime = 4294968` and reload `fail2ban` service, the entry in the `iptables` output is missing (the ipset is not created) and indeed, testing with, e.g., the `ab` utility shows that the ban is not enforced. Interestingly, using `banaction = iptables-multiport` works even for "large" bantimes. What might be the reason for this behavior? I am using fail2ban v 0.9.7 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't strictly a `fail2ban` related issue, bit rather a bug in `netfilter` code on your kernel. In short, your version of `ipset` has an integer overflow for `timeout` parameter, so you see an unpredictable behavior when it exceeds 32bit integer.

You don't see this with multiport as it does not use this code and instead relies on its own devices to track timeouts.

Here's a [link](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/158969/) to the patch for this issue in netfilter code.